# structuring element to remove 1 pixel connection

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-morphology

I have been thinking and searching for this but could found anything! can anyone help me on this to finding the structuring element

Image is attached :
[image: link to image]

Thanks

Comment: `if have neighbour (left AND right AND NOT up AND NOT down) OR (up AND down AND NOT left AND NOT right), then => kill pixel`

Comment: @Hoki Better watch out for the *"National Society for Prevention of Cruelty to Pixels"* 

Comment: what about the bottom right most pixel in the last example? it is also connected by only one pixel to the region above it?

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is to use a [hit or miss transformation](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/hitmiss.htm)/operation, it's the operation used in most of [skeleton/thinning transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hit-or-miss_transform). You look for a really specific pattern, and when you find it, you erase the central pixel.

In your case, you need to use structuring element like that:

```
? 1 ?                 ? 0 ?
0 1 0       or        1 1 1
? 1 ?                 ? 0 ?
```

with 0 and 1 meaning black and with pixels respectively, and ? is wild.

Comment: Thanks for help .. 
Will These structuring element work on above scenario using hit or miss ?

Comment: Yes they will do the work, but they might remove sometimes pixels they should not. If you take a look to your first example, the first SE will remove also the pixel (3,8) when using the top left corner as origin. In order to prevent that, you may add the constrain that at least three of the '?' must be a white pixel.

Comment: But I want no other pixel to remove or grow :/

Comment: You can still use the ones I gave you, but you check if at least 3 of the ? are white pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`bwmorph`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html), specifically the `'hbreak'` operation might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for response ! But I am looking for the structuring element/filter :)

Comment: I guess that does not work on the lower left example.